# Is there an easy to to iterate over all :NEW values from an Oracle database trigger execution?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am attempting to write a generic trigger that will provide all of the :NEW values for the row inserted.  Ultimately I want to turn them into XML and insert the XML string into a binary field on another table.

There are a variable number of columns in each table - many times over 100 fields and over 100 tables in all, so individual mapping to XML per table is extremely time consuming.

Is there a way to reference the :NEW pseudorecord as a collection of column values - or perhaps a way to pass the whole :NEW record to a Stored Procedure that could pass it to a Java function (hosted on the database) that might make the individual values iterable?

I've found an example here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm
    Create history table and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_history ( d DATE, old_obj t, new_obj t)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Tbl_Trg
  AFTER UPDATE ON tbl
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl_history (d, old_obj, new_obj)
  VALUES (SYSDATE, :OLD.OBJECT_VALUE, :NEW.OBJECT_VALUE);
END Tbl_Trg;
/
```

This seems to imply there is some sort of way it is storing all of the values as a variable, but this appears to put them directly back into a database table.  I want to get the 'text' values of the column values listed.

Comment: This is not related to [java]

Comment: I've accepted the edit.  I originally tagged it with Java because I suggested passing the :NEW object into a Java function hosted on the database.  After considering your edit, I agree that it would not put the question in front of the right people.  Thanks.

Comment: No,  Your trigger fires on each row updated.  There is no way to map :new to a generic collection of values. See here - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:734825535375

Comment: No, there is no generic/dynamic way to access the :NEW and :OLD values, you have to specify them individually, by name :-(

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching the internet for hours for a definitive answer.  Code to write code may be the best way to go.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @user681574 - does that mean you already know how to generate the triggers programmatically from the data dictionary?

Comment: @Alex Poole The asktom article from OldProgrammer above describes a way to accomplish the 'code to write code'.  It appears that it uses functions within the trigger creation to automate a significant portion of the trigger code.  I am not familiar with generating triggers programmatically from the data dictionary myself.

Comment: OK, I hadn't followed that link. I was thinking of a procedure to generate/create the trigger, rather than a temporary script; and could have that generate XML. I won't bother adapting and posting what I have if you have it hand though *8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure to create your trigger

for table tbl like

```
create table tbl (id number, value varchar2(10));
```

and an history table like

```
create table tbl_history (d date,id number, value varchar2(10));
```

you can create your trigger like this

```
create or replace procedure CREATE_TRIGGER IS
    trig_str VARCHAR2(32767);
    col_str VARCHAR2(32767) := '(d';
    values_str VARCHAR2(32767) := '(sysdate';
begin
    trig_str := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Tbl_Trg AFTER UPDATE ON tbl FOR EACH ROW'||chr(10)||
    'BEGIN'||chr(10)||chr(9)||'INSERT INTO tbl_history ';

    for col in (
        SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where table_name = 'TBL'
    ) loop
        col_str := col_str||','||col.column_name;
        values_str := values_str||','||':OLD.'||col.column_name;
    end loop;
    col_str := substr(col_str,1,length(col_str)-1)||')';
    values_str := substr(values_str,1,length(values_str)-1)||')';
    trig_str := trig_str||col_str||' VALUES '||values_str||';'||chr(10)||'END;';

    execute immediate trig_str;
END;
/
```

With an history table with old and new values it's a bit more complicated but same idea

Comment: Thanks, this must be marked as the best answer.